# Use angular filter outside the angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to format dates on the client-side using angular date filter. I'd like to do that way, because I use angular in some places of my application and I'd like my dates to be formatted uniformly in the whole app.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
function formatDatetime(date, format) {
  var ngDateFilter = angular.getDateFilter(); //that's what I'm asking about
  return ngDateFilter(date, format);
}
```

I use angular applications only on several pages, but dates are spread over various pages (with and without angular app).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, as usual I've found an answer. I did:

```
angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$filter")("date");
```

and it's OK.

**EDIT**

As meze observed, I could have also used:

```
angular.injector(["ng"]).get("dateFilter")
```

An example with number filter for currency:

```
var filter = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$filter")("number");

$('#Price').val(filter(price));
```

Comment: I think you can do `angular.injector(["ng"]).get("dateFilter");` but not sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Thankyou! I will add an example

Comment: Thanks! Here's a more accurate usage for currency:
```var filter = window.angular.injector(['ng']).get('$filter')('currency'); var formatted = filter(price,'$')
```